# How to customize or replace OAuth2 login screen in Fiware IdM Keyrock

Tags: django, mobile, authentication, fiware

We have a login flow starting from a smartphone. The login, registration and authorization screens provided by Keyrock / Horizon are not mobile friendly. We want to change the layout to accomodate smaller screens and change the logo.

How can we customize or replace the login, registration and authorization screens?
Horizon seems to be written in python/Django. I am new to Django and ideally just want to change a bunch of html templates somewhere. Is this possible? Or do we need Django expertise to accomplish this? Also i want the changes not to be overridden (or at least require minimal work to re-apply them) if we update the Keyrock software to a newer version later on.

We will be hosting our own Keyrock IdM once we are satisfied it does what we need it to, but are currently testing with the Fiware labs Keyrock instance.

The github sources https://github.com/ging/horizon/tree/master/horizon/templates/horizon
and documentation are not forthcoming on this subject. Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are right in that certain screens are not mobile friendly. I'll add it to the backlog to fix it in upcoming releases so the FIWARE Lab instance is more mobile friendly.

Secondly, if you want to modify the screens in your own instance you will have to edit the templates of the corresponding screens. The IdM is built using [bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/) and [django templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/templates/). You don't need to be an expert in django to modify this templates but I would recommend learning the template language basics.

The templates are located [here](https://github.com/ging/horizon/tree/master/openstack_dashboard/templates). Specifically, you will need to modify:
- [login screen](https://github.com/ging/horizon/blob/master/openstack_dashboard/templates/auth/login.html)
- [registration screen](https://github.com/ging/horizon/tree/master/openstack_dashboard/templates/auth/registration)
- authorization screen

If you encounter any problem you can ask here or [open an issue](https://github.com/ging/fiware-idm/issues) in the official repo.

Cheers!